# IBM Notes FTSearch: searching multi-value number fields

Tags: full-text-search, lotus-notes

Is it possible to do a *full-text search* in Notes (LotusScript or Java, or simply in the search bar) using a *number field* containing *multiple values*? E.g.

```
field xyz > 1000 and field xyz < 2000
```

so that any of the available values is used for the test?

What we see here is that documents with multiple values in the field xyz are just excluded from the results. Only documents with a single value field xyz are shown.

Can it be done, or is it just impossible?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think full-text search will work in your situation. Maybe you can try ordinary search and put results in a folder.

```
Dim s As New NotesSession   
Dim db As NotesDatabase
Dim collection As NotesDocumentCollection
Dim query As String

Set db = s.Currentdatabase

query = { Field1 > 1000 & Field1 < 2000 }
Set collection = db.Search(query, Nothing, 0)

MsgBox "Documents found: " & collection.Count

Call collection.PutAllInFolder( "MyFolderWithResults" )
```

Instead of putting collection in a folder you can also perform full-text search on the resulting collection `collection.FTSearch`.